# photo upload - call ajax to delete image if browser is closed

Tags: php, ajax

I have a PHP picture upload form, so user can send one picture and in next step he can crop this image and some other functions.

My problem is, the user can send many pictures without finished the process so this pictures will be stored in my server and will have no utility.

So I think to solve it using ajax, show an alert when user try to close/leave the page asking if he is sure about this and if he is, call an ajax to delete the image.

I found a function using javascript, but I need one using JQUERY to be able to use AJAX to delete the picture:

```
function setConfirmUnload(on) {
    window.onbeforeunload = (on) ? unloadMessage : null;
}

function unloadMessage() {
    return "Are you sure you want to leave this page";
}
```

is it a good idea? how can I solve this? Any jquery examples or php ideas to avoid storing unecessary uploaded images on my server?

Comment: This isn't always going to help. Consider if the user's browser, computer, or network connection dies after uploading the image. A better approach might be to attach an expiry time to the image, and automatically delete the image if the user hasn't finished the process before it expires. This doesn't help with potential DOS attacks by uploading lots of images and filling the disk space however.

Comment: @PenguinBrian thank you friend! I think about 2 solutions: mysql table to store images that user hasn't finished the process and delete it after some time or upload pictures to a TEMP folder (with date name), if user finishes the process move to permanent folder, so I can delete this temp folder every day.